# Selected not working with options_from_collection_for_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
line belongs_to :manufacturer
```

I have the following code in a lines edit view

```
<%= f.select :manufacturer_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Manufacturer.all, :id, :name, {:selected => @line.manufacturer}) %>
```

It is not showing the the current @line.manufacturer as selected. Similar code works elsewhere so I can only assume it is a result of using `options_from_collection_for_select`.

I tried to alter it with reference to the comments [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select) but couldn't get that to work.

What is the solution?

Comment: Did you try to use :selected => @line.manufacturer_id ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `options_from_collection_for_select` method signature calls for an integer as the fourth parameter whereas you are passing a hash. Try

```
<%= f.select :manufacturer_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Manufacturer.all, :id, :name, @line.manufacturer.id) %>
```

NOTE: As per [this comment](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select#450-Selected-parameter-needs-an-int), the `selected` parameter needs to be an integer ID.

Comment: Great. Thank you. So obvious and yet I couldn't see it. I actually can see that where I thought the code was working the same elsewhere it was actually using the id not he object. Sometimes it needs another pair of eyes. Thank you thank you.